# How to extract the y-coordinate of the turtle as a floating number - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, turtle-graphics

I'm working on a python program to create circles and ellipses in Minecraft, or for whatever pegboard system you can think of. It will be basically the same thing  [as this tool right here](https://donatstudios.com/PixelCircleGenerator), but I'm writing my own code. I'm using the turtle module to draw a grid first, and then go back through with the circle/ellipse. However, I need a way to extract the coordinates of the turtle.

If t=turtle.Turtle(), then using the command t.position() returns something like (200.00,180.00). I need to be able to extract the y coordinate and do operations with it. Any ideas?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract just the Y coordinate via:

```
y = t.ycor()
```

When you extract the position via `t.position()`, you get back a `Vec2D`.  This is essentially a tuple of floats but prints in a more truncated (two decimal places) form than a regular tuple of floats.  But it has the same precision:

```
>>> t.circle(100, 36)
>>> t.position()
(58.78,19.10) 
>>> t.ycor()
19.09830056250525
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the second element of the tuple: `t.position()[1]`